# Mern stack: TypeError: Search.find() (or Search.findById() / Search.findOne()) is not a function?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am about to develop a component that fetches data from my database with mern stack. I got this error with insomnia and I have changed the code multiple times. 
error:

> TypeError: Search.find is not a function
>       at C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\server.js:28:8
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search -
>   Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search -
>   Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at jsonParser (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:119:7)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search -
>   Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at jsonParser (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search - Copy\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:119:7)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\yasmin\search engine\search -
>   Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

my code contains:

search.model.js:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Search = new Schema(
  {
    imagePath: { type: String, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { collection: "search" }
);

module.export = mongoose.model("Search", Search);
```

My server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router = express.Router();
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

let Search = require("./models/search.model");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
  Search.find({}, function (err, search) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json("Error: " + err);
    } else {
      res.json(search);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

and since I am doubting that there is a missing dependency so I am posting my Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.6"
  }
}
```

i want to add that my server is connected to the MongoDB database and I have created a collection named search manually to fetch data from. when I open my MongoDB client and use the method db.collection.find() it works perfectly.